# Unable to set selected value with easyDropDown.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am attempting to use the easyDropDown.js add on to style my drop boxes but I have encountered an issue. My drop box is not statically created. When the webpage is loaded an array is used to append the drop down list. This drop box appears on multiple pages of my website and I am attempting to set it up so that when the user makes a selection on one page, that selection carries to every page.

Here's a step by step play-through of what the code is doing:

When the page is started it appends the easyDropDown list so that all the values are there.

```
$('#homeSelectSite').empty();

s = "";
s = "<option value='site'>Site</option>";
for (var i = 0; i < Sites.length; i++) {
     s = s + "<option value='" + Sites[i].SiteID + "'>" + Sites[i].SiteID + " " + Sites[i].SiteName + "</option>";
}
$('#homeSelectSite').append(s);
```

Note: Sites is the array that I am using to fill the drop box.

Now once the drop box list has been created I need to set what value is selected. This value is set in the sessionStorrage if the user has made a selection on another page.

```
$('#homeSelectSite').easyDropDown();
var selectedSite = sessionStorage.getItem("CurrentSiteID");
if (selectedSite != undefined && selectedSite != null) {
    $('#homeSelectSite').val(selectedSite);
}
```

So what the code is doing is this: emptying the current drop box, appending it with new values, styling it with easyDropDown, and finally setting the selected value. For some reason this will not work. The appending and styleing are working just fine but it will not allow me to set the selected value. I have also tried using this:

```
$('#homeSelectSite').easyDropDown('select', selectedSite);
```

Is there a reason why I cannot set the selected value? This all works if I remove everything related to easyDropDown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar issue today as I was trying to set the selected value of a dropdown using easyDropDown.

What I did to fix it was to find out the index of the to-be selected option, rather than selecting it by value.

In your case it would be something like:

```
var index = 0;
$('#homeSelectSite option').each(function(i, item) {
   if ($(this).val() === selectedSite) {
     index = i;
   }
});
$('#homeSelectSite').easyDropDown('select', index);
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like there's a bug in easyDropDown 2.1.4

Line 326 should be changed from:

`index = self.$select.find('option[value='+index+']').index() - 1;`

to:

`index = self.$select.find('option[value='+index+']').index();`

This will only solve the fact that easyDropDown was selecting the previous item instead of the one you wanted, but I'm not sure this would solve your issue. And yes, you must use the 'select' method from the plugin instead of 'val'.